# How to use unnamed function arguments in C or C++

Tags: c++, function, arguments

How do I use function arguments declared like

```
void f(double)
{
    /**/
}
```

if it is possible?

Comment: __No__. Just add a name it will not break a previous declaration

Answer (score 42, accepted):

I hope an example can provide some help:

```
// Declaration, saying there is a function f accepting a double.
void f(double);

// Declaration, saying there is a function g accepting a double.
void g(double);

// ... possibly other code making use of g() ... 

// Implementation using the parameter - this is the "normal" way to use it. In
// the function the parameter is used and thus must be given a name to be able
// to reference it. This is still the same function g(double) that was declared
// above. The name of the variable is not part of the function signature.
void g(double d)
{
  // This call is possible, thanks to the declaration above, even though
  // the function definition is further down.
  f(d);
}

// Function having the f(double) signature, which does not make use of 
// its parameter. If the parameter had a name, it would give an 
// "unused variable" compiler warning.
void f(double)
{
  cout << "Not implemented yet.\n";
}
```

Comment: This is the best answer here. +1.

Comment: @zed91 - You should mark the answer that helped you solve the problem as "accepted". You can mark any answer as accepted, regardless of the voting score. It is considered polite to always accept an answer for your questions. It will also get you +2 in reputation and the author of the answer +15.

Comment: Other use cases for this are passing function pointers around and templates.

Answer (score 2):

No. You have to give it a name. I.e.

```
void f(double myDouble)
{
    printf("%f", myDouble * 2);
}
```

or if you are using iostreams:

```
void f(double myDouble)
{
    cout << myDouble * 2;
}
```

Comment: @Alan: `varargs.h` and the varargs syntax and support.

Comment: @Alan: The question is equally applicable to C or C++, so I used the C function.

Comment: @dmckee: I'm referring to: http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/input-output.html#faq-15.1

Comment: @Alan: I know that, but that doesn't mean others won't read this and find it applicable elsewhere.

Comment: @Billy: Use `%f` or `%g` to printf a double.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one good [link](http://www.comeaucomputing.com/techtalk/#argwithnoname)

```
void bar(int arg1, int /* Now unnamed */, int arg3)
{
    // code for bar, using arg1 and arg3
}
```

> Sometimes though, the above approach is not just used to support legacy code, but also to make sure an overloaded function gets picked, perhaps a constructor. In other words, passing an additional argument just to make sure a certain function gets picked. As well, during code development it might help to use an unnamed argument if, for instance, you write stubs for some routines.
>
> When possible, it probably should be argued that unused parameters should be removed completely both from the function and from all the call points though, unless your specifically trying to overload operator new or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

The parameter may still get placed onto the stack, so you may be able to find it there (see comments below)

For *example* only (**highly non-portable**)

```
#include<stdio.h>
void f(double)
{
    double dummy;
    printf("%lf\n",*(&dummy-2)); //offset of -2 works for *my* compiler
}

int main()
{
    f(3.0);
}
```

I'm not sure why you'd want to do this though

Comment: This is highly implementation-dependent (depends on CPU, ABI, etc).

Comment: @Paul R. It's my interpretation of the question. At least until the OP clarifies it. I added a note to my answer

Comment: noted, and -1 removed. Suggest you also `s/will/may/` and `s/can/may be able to/`, as there are plenty of ABIs which use registers for passing parameters.

Comment: Arguments aren't necessarily passed on the stack. More likely to be passed in a register, for example if using SSE2 FP (quite likely).

Comment: I don't see the value in this at all. There is really nothing we can tell the OP about where to find that data. If he has the ability to search for it, he has the ability to give the argument a name.

Comment: You should not write this down on the internet, this should not even be mentioned. People will use this.

Answer (score -2):

Compiler will pass 0 by default....its the way we used to distinguish postfix increment operator and we never have to use the actual value passed..

Comment: Unnamed arguments are unrelated and uncorrelated to default values. Unless the person who declared the function with the unnamed argument also told it to default to 0, the compiler does not "pass 0 by default", and the caller can - and must - pass in a specific value, albeit one that is unusable due to not having an identifier. The edge case of `operator++` or `operator--` is an unfortunate shortcoming in the design that is now set in stone, but it has no relation to how all other unnamed or default args act.