# What does this C++ code segment do?

Tags: c++, boost, error-code

can someone tell me what this code does?

```
const boost::system::error_code&
```

i suspect that this code is used to connect to the function via a pointer,
but is it everything what it does?

there is full code:

```
    #include <iostream>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/date_time/posix_time/posix_time.hpp>

void print(const boost::system::error_code&)
{
    std::cout<<"hello word\n";
}
int main()
{
  boost::asio::io_service io;

  boost::asio::deadline_timer t(io, boost::posix_time::seconds(5));
  t.async_wait(&print);
  io.run();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Could you show more code, context, a reason for your question??

Comment: It specifies a type, but without the rest of the statement it doesn't do anything.

Comment: this may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2490456/how-to-use-unnamed-function-arguments-in-c-or-c

Comment: @downvoters, without the edit the question wasn't very good, with the edit, it's a fair question - even if asked slightly incorrectly - go easy on the OP.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know `boost::asio`, but I suspect that `boost::asio::deadline_timer::async_wait()` needs a function taking a single argument of the type `const boost::system::error_code&`. In order to call `async_wait()`, you will have to pass a pointer to such a function.

`void print(const boost::system::error_code&)` is such a function.

If you do not want to use a function argument, you can leave it unnamed. That prevents warnings compilers typically emit when you are not using one of the function arguments provided.